# Stop matching when a certain character is reached

Tags: javascript, regex

I've the following regex which needs to stop matching when it encounters a hash.

### Regex:

`/[?&]+([^=&]+)=([^&]*)/gi`

### URL Sample:

`http://website.com/1068?page=4&taco=cat#tasty`

The above regex will capture `cat#tasty` instead of just `cat` in the last capture group. I attempted the following which works ONLY if a hash is present.

### Regex Test:

`/[?&]+([^=&]+)=([^&]*)#/gi`

If the url doesn't have a hash, it won't match. making the hash optional — `#?` — doesn't work either as the greedy `*` of the last capture group still grabs `cat#tasty`.

Comment: Are you writing your own URL parser?  If not, consider using one that is already written.

Comment: It's just a simple javascript line to pull the url params, one line, no need to include something larger.

Comment: Be mindful that http://domain.com/this=is/a=valid?url=and#you=need&to_use=a_parser because the only actual parameter in that URL is url=and :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
/[?&]+([^=&]+)=([^&#]*)/gi
```

Although as Ray pointed out, there are many url parsers available.

Comment: Simpler than I thought. It always is when you attack it thinking it's more complicated than it is.

Answer (score 2):

A little-known way to parse URLs in JavaScript is to simply create an a element and give it the url as the href attribute!

```
var link=document.createElement('a')
link.href="http://website.com/1068?page=4&taco=cat#tasty"
alert(link.search) //?page=4&taco=cat
alert(link.hash) //#tasty
```

Just tossing this out there. If you do your regex on just link.search (or perhaps link.search.substr(1)) you won't have to worry about ever matching anything but parameters.

Comment: In that same breath, couldn't I just use location.search and skip the element creation?

Comment: You could, if the URL you were trying to parse was the current one!

Comment: It is indeed :D Thanks for your answer though, it's good to know I can access `.search` on an `href`.